# Reflect db engine when using Application factory

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm restructuring a Flask application to use Blueprints and Application Factories. I've read the documentation for using Application Factories at: [Application Factories](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/#using-applications). However, the documentation seems to be manually creating models. I want to reflect tables from an existing database. I get the following error upon reflecting the engine:

```
RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context
```

I'm calling `db.init_app(app)` and then using the application context, calling `create_all` to create my models. At this point, doesn't the application now have a db engine and isn't it bound to the flask app object?

`__init__.py`:

```
from database import db
from flask import Flask

def create_app(config_file):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile(config_file)

    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    return app
```

`database.py`:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

`models.py`:

```
from database import db

class Trailer(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['tr_trailer']
```

*****UPDATE*****

I've updated the app to reflect the engine within the application context.

```
with app.app_context():
        db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)
        db.create_all()
```

However, now I'm receiving key errors on my tables:

```
__table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['tr_trailer']
KeyError: 'tr_trailer'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with model import causing KeyError. I've delayed the import of the model to where I required it in the views function -

```
@blueprint.route('/some_route', method('GET','POST')
def some_route():
  from blueprint.path.models import TabObj
  return str(db.session.query(db.func.count(TabObj.colname)).scalar())
```